# Update query to run through a Loop to update many rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I rarely use update statements in my dealings with SQL and get a little nervous when doing so. In a previous issue i raised it was decided i needed to add an identity columns into some tables to be used as surrogate Key. Given the 1.7 million rows I would like to do this as smoothly as possible. So what i need to do is run an update that loops through and updates each field with the relevant data.

Table 1: tblPostCodeLookup

```
Postcode | Postcode ID
AB44     | 1
AB45     | 2
```

Table 2: tblPostcodeStreetView

```
ID | Postcode | Postcode ID
1  | AB446TR  | 1
2  | AB447TY  | 1
3  | AB457HH  | 2
```

I've got as far as doing the basic update

```
UPDATE    tblPostcodesStreetsView
SET              PostcodeID = 1
WHERE     (postcode LIKE 'AB44%')
```

However getting this to run through and update each one is causing me issue's!

Comment: I ideally need it to look through each postcode variance. So if its AB44 it updates it to a one, if ab45 a 2, ab46 a 3 and so one going through the list of ID's

Comment: @Gavlaaa So till which number do you have PostCode? Which is the first PostCode AB44 to ?

Comment: @mr_eclair table one has the ID in that needs to go into table two where the postcode matches. So where the postcode in table 2 matches 1 it then updates it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
UPDATE  psv
SET              PostcodeID = pcl.PostcodeID
FROM    tblPostcodesStreetsView psv
         INNER JOIN
        tblPostCodeLookup pcl
          on
            pcv.postcode LIKE pcl.postcode + '%'
```

should do the trick. Unless there are multiple rows in `tblPostCodeLookup` which will match the same row in `tblPostcodesStreetsView` - in which case, which `PostCodeID` is assigned is not well defined.

[`UPDATE`...`FROM`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) is SQL Server dialect, it's not standard SQL. A standards approach would be something like:

```
UPDATE  tblPostcodesStreetsView
SET     PostcodeID = (select pcl.PostcodeID from tblPostCodeLookup pcl
                 where tblPostcodesStreetsView.postcode LIKE pcl.postcode + '%')
```

Which will at least produce an error for the above scenario of multiple matches I mentioned.

Comment: +1 for "Unless there are multiple rows ... in which case, which PostCodeID is assigned is not well defined."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Spot on and luckily there are no multiple rows! Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Sanity check what the results would look like:

```
SELECT tblPostcodeStreetView.Postcode
     , tblPostCodeLookup.Postcode
     , tblPostCodeLookup.Postcode_ID
FROM   tblPostcodeStreetView
 INNER
  JOIN tblPostCodeLookup
    ON tblPostcodeStreetView.Postcode LIKE tblPostCodeLookup.Postcode + '%'
```

Make this an update statement

```
UPDATE tblPostcodeStreetView
SET    Postcode_ID = tblPostCodeLookup.Postcode_ID
FROM   tblPostcodeStreetView
 INNER
  JOIN tblPostCodeLookup
    ON tblPostcodeStreetView.Postcode LIKE tblPostCodeLookup.Postcode + '%'
```